# Prove that $\{x_{n}\} \subseteq A$ a Cauchy sequence $\Rightarrow$ $\{f(x_{n}\}\} \subseteq y$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(Y,\rho)$ be a metric space and let $A \subseteq Y$ be a dense subset. Prove that $\{x_{n}\} \subseteq A$ a Cauchy sequence $\Rightarrow$ $\{f(x_{n}\}\} \subseteq y$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Idea : $A$ being dense $\Rightarrow \forall x \in X, \exists \{x_{n}\} \subseteq A, \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}x_{n} = x$. Help would be appreciated!

Sorry everyone. $Y$ is a complete metric space. and $f$ is continuous

Comment: What is $f$? Perhaps a non-increasing map?

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936321/is-functions-of-cauchy-sequences-is-also-cauchy/936335#936335.

Comment: You need uniform continuity (it's one possible hypothesis )

Answer (score 1):

Is $Y$ complete and $f$ continuous? If yes, then the statement is very straight forward by applying continuity and completeness.

If not, then $Y=(0,\infty)$, $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap Y$, $f:Y\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, and $x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, serves as a counter example. Note that $f(x_{n})=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f$ is continuous.

**Edit:** Now since we have established that $Y$ must be complete, then use the fact that every Cauchy sequence in $Y$ converges, and if $x_{n}\to x$ then $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$ since $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Oh crap. Sorry about that. $Y$ is in fact complete.